# Rewriting a program without using goto statements

Tags: c++, algorithm

I had to program a similar problem using goto statements.  Now we are asked to rewrite our code without using goto statement. I don't know how to begin doing this program.  I paste in the previous program code using the goto.

```
// Eight Queens problem using one dimesional array and goto statement

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int q[8];
    q[0] = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int count = 0;

NC: //cout  << "Next column\n" << "Column = " << c << endl;
    c++;
    if (c == 8) goto print;
    q[c] = -1;

NR: //cout << "Next row\n" << "Row = " << q[c] << "\nColumn = " << c << endl;
    q[c]++;
    if (q[c] == 8) goto backtrack; 
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){
        if(q[i] == q[c] || abs(q[c] - q[i]) == (c - i))
            goto NR;
    }
    goto NC;

backtrack:
    //cout << "Backtrack" << endl;
    //cout <<"Column = " << c << endl;
    c--;
    if(c == -1) return 0;
    goto NR;

print:
    //cout << "print" << endl;
    ++count;
    cout << count << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++){
            cout << q[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    goto backtrack;


    return 0;
}
```

This program is a hint the professor posted for the class to use.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include<cstdlib>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;

    bool ok(int q[], int col){
    if the configuration is “bad” return false;
    else
    return true;
    }

    void backtrack(int &col){
    col--;
    if(col==-1) exit(1);
    }

    void print(int q[]){
    static int count =0;
    print the array q
    }

    int main(){
    int q[8]; q[0]=0;
    int c=1;
    // from_backtrack keeps track if we need to reset the row to the
    // top of the current colum or not.

    bool from_backtrack=false;
    // The outer loop keeps looking for solutions
    // The program terminates from function backtrack
    // when we are forced to backtack into column -1
    while(1){
    while(c<8){ //this loop goes across columns
    // if we just returned from backtrack, use current value of row
    // otherwise get ready to start at the top of this column
    if(!from_backtrack) // we did not just return from backtrack
    Code goes here
    from_backtrack=false;
    while(q[c]<8){ // place queen in this column
    q[c]++;
    // if row=8, there is no valid square in this column
    // so backtrack and continue the loop in the previous column
    Code goes here
    //if this position is ok, place the queen
    // and move on (break) to the next column,
    // otherwise keep looking in this column
    Code goes here
    }
    c++; // placed ok, move to the next column
    }
    // one complete solution found, print it.
    print(q); // board completed, print it out
    backtrack(c);
    from_backtrack=true;
    }
    }
```

And this is an attempted I've made to completed the program

```
// NoGoto.cpp.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



bool attack(int q[], int col){
    if(q[i] == q[c] || abs(q[c] - q[i]) == (c - i)) return false;
    else
        return true;
} // Attack

void backtrack(int & col){
    col--;
    if(col == -1) exit(1);
} // Backtrack

void print(int q[]){
    static int count = 0;
    ++count;
    cout << count << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        cout << q[i];
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    int q[8];
    q[0] = 0;
    int c = 1;

    bool from_backtrack = false;

    while(1){
        while(c < 8){ // this loops across columns

            if(!from_backtrack)
                attack(q[c],c)

            from_backtrack = false;

            while(q[c] < 8){ // place queen in this column
                q[c]++;

    return 0;
}
```

"I'm having problem writing the code. How [can I] call each function to make it correctly find the solutions?"

Comment: There is no real question here as it stands.  Please clarify what you're having issues with.  What doesn't work?  What don't you understand?

Comment: It's pretty relieving yet shocking to see you as a student indenting your code better than your professor does — even if it's semi-pseudocode.

Comment: So the professor made you write a version of the program with `goto` ? Interesting.

Comment: This looks [familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817011/dumb-8-queens-problem-in-c-using-goto-and-backtrack).

Comment: @jeffamaphone I'm having problem writing the code.  How to call each function to make it correctly find the solutions.

Comment: @Mister Bunker: You might want to state your question explicitly otherwise it will be closed (as a duplicate) [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852077/8-queens-using-one-array).

Comment: Did the professor really not indent the code? That would drive me nuts and I'd have to reformat the whole thing before reading it.

Comment: @Jeff M All the questions I've asked so far are for the same problem but different methods to solve it.  This project is using the one dimensional array queens problem with the goto statement, rewriting the problem without the goto statement.  I'm asking for help on how to do it because Im lost.

Comment: @Mister Bunker: I added your question explicitly to your question.

Comment: @kirk.burleson: Microsoft has got you covered. In Visual Studio you just press C-k C-d to reformat the document. Don't like it? Change the way it formats the code in Tools > Options > Text Editor > `Your language here` > Formatting :)

Answer (score 7):

First, just look at the control flow by stripping everything else and adding explicit `goto`s for execution that reaches a label by straight-line execution.

```
NC: if (…) goto print;
    goto NR;

NR: if (…) goto backtrack;
    if (…) goto NR;
    goto NC;

backtrack:
    if (…) return;
    goto NR;

print:
    goto backtrack;
```

Now, take the unconditional gotos and try to move the blocks so they represent straight-line execution.

```
NR: if (…) goto backtrack;
    if (…) goto NR;
    goto NC;

NC: if (…) goto print;
    goto NR;

print:
    goto backtrack;

backtrack:
    if (…) return;
    goto NR;
```

Now eliminate the straight-line gotos

```
NR: if (…) goto backtrack;
    if (…) goto NR;

NC: if (…) goto print;
    goto NR;

print:

backtrack:
    if (…) return;
    goto NR;
```

Note that a label with all backward-going gotos is a loop:

```
for (;;) {
NR: if (…) goto backtrack;
    if (…) continue;

NC: if (…) goto print;
    continue;

print:

backtrack:
    if (…) return;
}
```

Hmm, we can reverse the sense of the `NC: if()` and eliminate the `goto print`. And the `goto backtrack` just jumps over some statements, which is equivalent to another reversed `if`.

```
for (;;) {
NR: if (! …) {
        if (…) continue;
NC:     if (! …) continue;
print:
    }
backtrack:
    if (…) return;
}
```

The loop has no condition, but `backtrack: … if(…) return;` just exits it, so move that block and the condition into the loop.

```
for (;…; /* backtrack */ …) {
NR: if (! …) {
        if (…) continue;
NC:     if (! …) continue;
print:
    }
}
```

Looking pretty good, no more gotos and no "suspicious" structure! However, `NC` is supposed to be the entry point.

This is where blind, mechanistic, compiler-ish transformations fail. I see three alternatives:

1. Introduce variables to force execution there for the first loop iteration. This is uglier than `goto`, in my opinion.
2. Disguise a `goto NC;` as a `switch(0)` and call label `NC:` as `case 0:`. The teacher will probably not accept this compromise.
3. Copy the blocks from `NC` to the end of the loop and paste above the beginning of the loop. You can then factor them out into functions. Actually, this is a blind, mechanistic transformation. Hooray. I'll also represent `NR` and `backtrack` as functions for uniformity.

.

```
NC();
if (…) {
    print();
}

while ( backtrack(), … ) { // <- note comma operator
    NR();
    if (! …) {
        if (…) continue;
        NC();
        if (! …) continue;
        print();
    }
}
```

There is probably a more elegant solution that involves looking at the contents of the code, but this takes less thinking.

Comment: Wow. That's such a thorough answer. I wish I could give more than +1.

Comment: @Josh: Well… it's a lot of copy-paste, and I didn't test it. It's FWIW; the result is nontrivial but the process is roughly what an automatic decompiler would do. I don't think it gives OP an unfair advantage; probably he has not studied this kind of thing and the prof is just being a pain (albeit pedagogical) by asking him to code without goto.

Comment: +1, I like this mechanical approach -- it could even be an automatica refactoring.

Comment: @Edmund: It would be nice. I've read a fair amount of assembly code and I took two semesters of compilers but I wouldn't want to attempt a decompiler… there's a big difference between a person choosing operations to perform and a program that's really on its own. Also, I took a few shortcuts and I'm really not even sure the answer is correct.